# create padding after blue border

Tags: html, css

how to add white space (approx 4px) after blue border.
I have tried a lot. Can you please tell me how I can add more padding after blue border

```
<img src="./profile.jpg" class="border-2 border-blue-400 bg-white p-1 z-10">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your image with `<div>` as border, and then add your padding.

1. Use `inline-block` so that `<div>` size fits content width (image)
   .
2. However, by default, `<img>` is rendered as **inline**, so there will be extra space below the image. You can adjust `<img>` **display** so it's not inline or set **vertical-align** to middle.
3. Set your border and padding.

```css
.outer{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img{
  /*vertical-align:middle;*/
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"> 
</div>
```